# field of characteristic $p$ be algebraically closed?

Tags: field-theory

Can a field of characteristic $p$ be algebraically closed?

I know finite fields cannot be algebraically closed, but there are also infinite fields of characteristic $p$, so can they be algebraically closed? If not, what is a good\easy counterexample.

Comment: algebraic closure K of $F_p$

Comment: What about equation $px+1=0$?

Comment: @MichaelGaluza What about it? That equation is simply $\;0=1\;$ over a field of characteristic $\;p\;$ , and thus false in any case.

Comment: @Timbuc, and therefore have no roots

Comment: @MichaelGaluza The very same thing can be said about the equation $\;0=1\;$ over **any** field...but there is no polynomial of degree greater than zero here! Are you  implying there are no closed fields of positive characteristic? Because that'd be false: there are.

Answer (score 5):

Every field has an algebraically closed extension called the algebraic closure. Now, the algebraic closure of a field of characteristic $p$ is again of characteristic $p$.

Answer (score 1):

Any field has an algebraic closure, whatever its characteristic. Also, a finite field cannot be algebraically closed.